# Mapear variables NaN en bytes

Tags: python, micropython

Estoy tratando de mapear donde hay elementos `NaN` en mis resultados. Para ello lo que pretendo hacer es crear un nueva variable que mediante 0 y 1 defina si hay o no `NaN`. Es decir, si tengo una lista de resultados como la siguiente,

```
lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN','0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']
```

Yo querría tener un resultado como:

```
map = 001001000001
```

Hasta aquí sería la idea con el concepto general. Ahora bien, yo todo esto lo tengo que enviar a un servidor por lo que necesito trabajar con `bytes`. Por lo tanto realmente lo que debería quedar es,

```
map = 00100100 y 00000001
```

Para ello empleo la librería `struct`, pues necesito `bytes` y no cadenas de caracteres.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora y da los resultados deseados, pues consigue trabajar en paquetes de 8 valores y hace la conversión, pero no me convence en cuanto a programación se refiere. ¿Existe una manera más óptima de conseguirlo?

```
import struct

lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN','0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']

final = []
while True:
    try:
        res = 0
        for i in range(8):
            if lista[i] == 'NaN':
                res = res + 2**i
            print('\t· ',lista[i],' >> ', res)
        final.append(res)
        
        for i in range(8):
            lista.pop(0)
        print('--')
    except:
      final.append(res)
      for cnt,i in enumerate(final):
        result = struct.pack('B', i)
        final[cnt] = result
      break

print('Servidor recibirá:',final)
```

**EDIT A Partir de la solución ofrecida por @Abulafia**

Micropython no permite emplear `[::-1]` por lo tanto he pensado esta pequeña modificación para intentar solucionar el problema, así cómo aportar más coherencia al desarrollo.

Además he introducido un valor más a la lista para evitar la confusión del valor capicúa.

```
lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN',0,'0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']
lista.reverse()
binario = "".join("1" if v == "NaN" else "0" for v in lista)
lista_bytes = [int(binario[i:i+8],2) for i in range(0, len(binario),8)]
final = [b.to_bytes(1, "little") for b in lista_bytes]
print('Servidor recibirá:',final)
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Observaciones previas

Los datos de entrada que proporcionas, convertidos a bits que indican las posiciones de los NaN, producen el valor binario:

```
001001000001
```

pero ya que eso son 12 bits y no 16 ¿cómo se decide por dónde partirlo en dos grupos y cómo rellenar con ceros los bytes resultantes incompletos?

Por otro lado observo que el ejemplo elegido es un poco desafortunado, porque el primer byte es "capicúa" (00100100) y no queda claro por tanto si debe leerse de derecha a izquierda o al revés. Sólo tras examinar tu código me doy cuenta de que ha sido construido "al revés", es decir, que el primer valor de la lista (11.325) da lugar al bit menos significativo del resultado. Esto es contraintuitivo, pero supongo que es así como lo necesitas.

Por tanto parece que tu algoritmo sería tomar los bits de 8 en 8 pero interpretados "de menor a mayor" para construir el primer byte y hacer lo mismo con los restantes, rellenando con ceros "por la derecha" (que se convierte en por la izquierda teniendo en cuenta que los procesamos de menor a mayor peso). Insisto, bastante confuso.

Por otro lado no veo claro cómo el receptor de esos bytes podrá decodificarlos correctamente sin saber que el total de bits significativos es 12. Sin ese dato no se sabría cuáles son los bits de relleno.

### Implementación

Dicho todo lo anterior, otra implementación que da como resultado exactamente lo que pides puede lograrse haciendo uso de la librería `bitarray`. Con esta librería no sólo se reduce el código (a un par de líneas) y se hace más legible, sino que además será más rápido pues `bitarray` está implementada internamente en C.

```
from bitarray import bitarray

lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN','0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']
b = bitarray((x == "NaN" for x in lista), endian="little")
print("Servidor recibirá", b.tobytes())
```

Atención al parámetro `endian="little"` que es el que hace que los bits dentro del bitarray se interpreten "de izquierda a derecha" a la hora de ser convertidos en bytes, como en tu implementación.

El resultado que sale es el mismo que cuando se ejecuta tu código:

```
Servidor recibirá b'$\x08'
```

Observa sin embargo que no es el resultado que describías en tu enunciado. El primer byte es el código ascii del '$', que es 00100100. El segundo byte es el código 0x08, que es 00001000 y no 00000001 como ponías en la descripción. De todas formas 0x08 es lo que producía también tu código para este ejemplo.

### Sin librerías externas

Ya que el OP indica en un comentario que está trabajando con micropython y prefiere no usar bibliotecas externas, aquí ofrezco otra implementación en python puro:

```
lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN','0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']
binario = "".join("1" if v == "NaN" else "0" for v in lista)
numeros = [int(binario[i:i+8][::-1],2) for i in range(0, len(binario),8)]
final = [b.to_bytes(1, "little") for b in lista_bytes]

print('Servidor recibirá:',final)
```

El resultado es el esperado: `[b'$', b'\x08']`.

Algunos trucos usados en el código:

- `"1" if v == "NaN" else "0" for v in lista` es una expresión generadora que va generando una serie de "1" y "0" a partir de la lista. Se le pasa como parámetro a `"".join()` para que los junte todos en una sola cadena. En el ejemplo esa cadena resultante contendría `"001001000001"`
- `int(binario[i:i+8][::-1],2)` toma 8 caracteres de la cadena `binario`, comprendidos entre la posición `i` e `i+8`. Les da la vuelta (el `[::-1]` es para eso) y pasa esa cadena a `int(..., 2)` que la interpreta en base 2 para producir un entero.
- Lo anterior se usa en una comprensión de listas para producir una lista de enteros a partir de la cadena contenida `binario`. En este ejemplo la lista de números resultante es `[36, 8]`. Estos son ya los valores (numéricos) de los bytes a enviar.
- Para convertirlos en datos de tipo byte se usa `int.to_bytes()` que requiere dos parámetros. El primero sería el número de bytes a generar (1 en este caso) y el segundo la *endianity*. Siendo un solo byte lo mismo da poner "little" que "big" en este caso.

Observa que el uso de `to_bytes()` hace innecesario el uso del módulo `struct`.

### Adaptado a micropython

Parece que micropython no implementa todo el lenguaje, sino un subconjunto. En particular no soporta el parámetro *step* en los *slices*, lo que impide usar el truco `[::-1]` para dar la vuelta a la cadena.

Puede hacerse usando `reversed()`, pero es necesario convertir el resultado en una cadena de nuevo con `"".join()`. El código queda farragoso, pero funciona (esta vez lo he comprobado con el intérprete online de [micropython.org](https://micropython.org/unicorn/))

```
lista = [11.325,99.3696,'NaN','0',0,'NaN',0,0,0,88,0,'NaN']
binario = "".join("1" if v == "NaN" else "0" for v in lista)
numeros = [int("".join(reversed(binario[i:i+8])),2) for i in range(0, len(binario),8)]
final = [b.to_bytes(1, "little") for b in numeros]

print('Servidor recibirá:',final)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es lo mismo "dar la vuelta a cada byte" como he hecho en el código anterior que "dar la vuelta a la lista" antes de procesarla, ya que en este último caso no sólo cambiaríamos de peso los bits, sino también de orden los bytes.

Comment: ¡Buenas, muchas gracias! Vayamos por partes, [UNO] en cuanto al orden si que es cierto que mi primer valor será 11.325 pero en la codificación si esto es contraintuitivo esto se puede girar, pues al decodificarlo simplemente hay que saber el orden de lectura. [DOS] El receptor sabe cuantos valores le llegarán, en este caso 12.

Comment: En cuanto al tema de `bitarray` es que trabajo en micropython (lo acabo de añadir, perdón) y estas librerías cómo `bytearray` me están dando problemas e intento no emplearlas.

Comment: @Lleims Ok. Edité la respuesta para darte otra implementación que no usa ningún módulo.

Comment: Mil disculpas, ayer simulé los datos con tu respuesta pero hoy los he probado en real. En micropython parece ser que no tampoco es posible emplear `[::-1]`. Teniendo en cuenta tus comentarios, estoy intentando hacer el mapeo de derecha a izquierda, y lo que hago es invertir la lista de datos y así luego evito tener que emplear `[::-1]`, es esto una "tontería" y se haría de otra forma o al menos gano en evitar esa confusión que mencionabas al principio? He añadido esta modificación a la pregunta. Muchas gracias y disculpa la insistencia.

Comment: @Lleims He actualizado la respuesta con una versión equivalente a la mia, pero que funciona en micropython

Comment: Aaargh, estuve cerca de la respuesta, mil gracias por la ayuda siempre.